# Custom UIView added in the interface builder does not load the xib

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have created custom `UIView` with a xib.

In addition I have a `UIViewController` in my storyboard, to which I have added a `UIView` and set its class to be my custom `UIView`.

But when I am running the app, the view doesn't have its subviews. When I debug, all the subviews are null.

In .m of the custom `UIView`, these init methods are present:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: how did you add the custom uiview to your viewcontroller?

Comment: What does "created custom UIView with a xib" mean here? Have you created a xib file, placed there the custom view as the root and added the subviews to it? And now you want to use the custom view with the subviews as the root view for a storyboard scene?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As you already know, with a `UIViewController` we have the `-initWithNibName:bundle:` method to connect it with an xib.
But...
When it comes to a `UIView`, you need to use `-loadNibNamed:owner:options:` and load it with the xib. (*simply specifying a custom class to the view in the xib won't work*)

---

### Suppose:

1. Created a `UIView` subclass called `CustomXIBView`

   - (*New File > Cocoa Touch > Objective-C Class -- Subclass of `UIView`*)
2. Created a Simple View User Interface and named it `CustomXIBView`

   - (*New File > User Interface > View*)

### Steps:

1. Go to `CustomXIBView`'s nib
2. Select `View` (*left toolbar*)
3. Select `Show Identity Inspector` (*3rd option in the panel on the right*)
4. Specify `CustomXIBView` as the **Custom Class** of the `View`

   - *don't do anything with `CustomXIBView`'s `File's Owner` in the nib*
5. Drag Drop Objects and connect it with `CustomXIBView.h`

### Code:

```
//To load `CustomXIBView` from any `UIViewController` or other class: 
//instead of the following commented code, do the uncommented code
//CustomXIBView *myCustomXIBViewObj = [CustomXIBView alloc] init];
//[myCustomXIBViewObj setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];

//Do this:
CustomXIBView *myCustomXIBViewObj = 
     [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"someView"
                                    owner:self
                                  options:nil]
                            objectAtIndex:0];
[myCustomXIBViewObj setFrame:CGRect(0, 
                                    0, 
                                    myCustomXIBViewObj.frame.size.width, 
                                    myCustomXIBViewObj.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:myCustomXIBViewObj];
```

---

ref: http://eppz.eu/blog/uiview-from-xib/

Comment: why [self addSubview:self.view]?

Comment: The debugger enters initWithCoder, but doesn't enter initWithFrame

Comment: This in the UIViewController didn't work either: self.RODE_RULS_CategoryView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CategoryView"
                                              owner:self
                                            options:nil]
                objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: your xib connections could be an issue. this will help -- http://eppz.eu/blog/uiview-from-xib/

Comment: @Luda : you set the **Custom Class** in the **View** or **File's owner**?

Comment: @Luda If you create your custom view not programmatically but with storyboard then storyboard runtime initializes the view with initWithCoder method and not with initWithFrame. So you should create the subviews in initWithCoder or preferably create method with common initialization code and call it from initWithCoder and initWithFrame.

Comment: @Luda : updated answer. _the second method was partially wrong_. so... instead i've added a tutorial link (for the 2nd method) in the answer. (_also, in the xib, the **Custom Class** must be specified for the **View** and not **File's Owner**_)

Comment: I have set the Custom Class in the View and the File's owner

Comment: @Luda : i believe you set it to **View** only. remove the **Custom Class** setting from **File's Owner**, right click on **File's Owner** and ensure there are no dangling xib connections. Then right click on **View** and ensure the xib connections are as per your requirement

Comment: Why creating the subviews in the interface builder isn't enough? Why should I create them programatically?

Comment: no @Luda , i didnt say programmatically. you infact should create the `subViews` in the IB but when you specify the `Custom Class` , it should be specified after selecting the `View` rather than the `File's Owner` ... this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nGAF0.png

Comment: Hi @staticVoidMan, Your proposal works: setting subviews in the IB and then put loadNibNamed in the uiviewcontroller. But what I was looking for (maybe mistakably, maybe this option doesn't even exist) Is to create the custom view and then in the IB of the UIViewController drag an UIView outlet, set its class to my custom UIView and not to write any code. Is it possible?

Comment: @staticVoidMan I have 5 views like this. I really do not want to code 5 times loadNibNamed. I want to just drag and drop them in the IB

Comment: @Luda : if you want your _custom_ `UIView` to have a separate xib for itself then sorry, i don't know of any way (_but i will try_). well... atleast this **custom class** thing is possible when you drag a `UIView` as a separate view in the same `UIViewController` but then there are limitations such as loading this extra _custom_ view from another `UIViewController`. lets see...